# Dojo Toolkit - adding dijit inside dijit (ex. button into ContentPane in AccordionContainer)

Tags: dojo, contentpane

I'm learning Dojo Toolkit and I'm fighting with adding dijit into dijit. There was similar post about it but wih DIV's. I just simply want to programmatically insert a button or anything else to a ContentPane like this:

[image]

I have a script (with required items to insert button):

```
       require(["dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/domReady!",  "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/_WidgetBase"],
        function(AccordionContainer, ContentPane, Button){
    var aContainer = new AccordionContainer({style:"height: 300px"}, "markup");    
    
    var aChild1 = new  ContentPane({
        title: "Date selectors",
        content: "Test"
    });       
   
    
    var aChild2 = new  ContentPane({
        title:"Group 2",
        content:"Test"
    });


    var aChild3 = new  ContentPane({
        title:"Group 3",
        content:"Test"
    });
    
            
    aContainer.addChild(aChild1);  
    aContainer.addChild(aChild2);
    aContainer.addChild(aChild3);      
    aContainer.startup();    
    
});
```

And my DIV is simply:

```
<div id="markup" style="width: 250px; height: 300px">
```

This `ContentPane` should work as left toolbar with rollable panes. In first one I'd like to add date pickers or button or anything else. Above code works until I try to add subChild. I tried to create var with button and make it child of a content pane like:

```
var btn as new Button([...]);
```

and place it here:

```
aContainer.addChild(aChild1);
aChild1.addChild(btn);
aContainer.addChild(aChild2);
aContainer.addChild(aChild3);      
aContainer.startup();
```

but it does not work. How can I build my layout in this case? Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I applied declarative instead of programatic creation:
In script, I simply added this line:

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/ContentPane"]);
```

Then I wrote some divs like:

```html
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane">
    Some text
</div>
```

I found a tip (inside the code of demos) that:

> content pane has no children so just use dojo's builtin after advice
> dojo.connect(dijit.layout.ContentPane.prototype, "resize",
> function(mb)
> ... so all I had to do was:

```js
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" data-dojo-props='selected:true, title:"Calendar"'>
                    <!-- calendar widget pane -->
                    <input id="calendar1" data-dojo-type="dijit.Calendar">
    </div>
```

If you would like to see, how to place any of layout items in one place, see Dojo Theme Tester (view source):
https://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.0/dojo-release-1.7.0/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=tundra

You will find every fragment well described. For me, it is more useful than documentation.

I hope that by solving my problem, this solution will be helpful to someone.